# Syntax error defining MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am using MYSQL Server version: 5.5.16 and having a very difficult time establishing my first trigger. Want to update a variable based on other values in a table whenever the table is updated. Following code produces syntax error ...#1193 - Unknown system variable 'status'

```
CREATE TABLE `peakstat` (
  `peakuid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(20)  ,
  `scheddate` date  ,
  `summitdate` date ,
PRIMARY KEY (`peakuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

and establishing the trigger ...

```
 delimiter $$
 drop TRIGGER if exists addstatus $$
 CREATE TRIGGER  addstatus 
 AFTER UPDATE ON  peakstat
   FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         IF peakstat.summitdate > 0 THEN
              set peakstat.status = "CLIMBED";
         ELSEIF peakstat.scheddate > NOW() THEN
              set peakstat.status = "SCHEDULED";
         END IF;
    END;$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: to clarify: `peakstat`.`status`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL After Insert and After Update Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843031/mysql-after-insert-and-after-update-trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use OLD or NEW clauses instead of table name. For example 'IF peakstat.summitdate > 0 THEN' has to be like this - 'IF NEW.summitdate > 0 THEN', and so on...
2. It is not possible to update records of triggered table in AFTER UPDATE trigger, change it to BEFORE UPDATE.

At the end we have something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS addstatus$$

CREATE TRIGGER addstatus
BEFORE UPDATE ON peakstat
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.summitdate > 0 THEN
    SET NEW.status = 'CLIMBED';
  ELSEIF NEW.scheddate > NOW() THEN
    SET NEW.status = 'SCHEDULED';
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am trying this but keep getting 'Unknown system variable 'test_var', any idea what's going on?

Comment: I do not use variable 'test_var' in my code. Check your solution.