# add value to My database

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code to calculate my values.
I used this one

```
$SQL = "SELECT itm_no,itm_nme,itm_tot,itm_sld, (itm_tot-itm_sld) 
AS itm_stk FROM itm_tot";
```

for get `itm_stk` value `(itm_tot-itm_sld)`.
then i want to add this `itm_stk` value to My database, `itm_stk` Column.
What should i Use?
Thanks.

Comment: You want to add another column tot he table?

Comment: Do you want to add the value to another table?

Comment: yes column name is itm_stk

Comment: not another table. i want to add this same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) which executes when a new row is inserted to `itm_tot` tables. What it should do is get the `(itm_tot-itm_sld)` and updated the `itm_stk`.

Read this : [MySQL After Insert and After Update Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843031/mysql-after-insert-and-after-update-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

//connect to localhost

if($_POST['Submit']=='Save')  `//on submittion of a form`
{
    $edit="UPDATE athi_table SET Name='".$_POST["Name"]."','".$_POST["Email"]."','".$_POST["Gender"]."','".$_POST["Degree"]."','".$_POST["Phone"]."','".$_POST["Skills"]."','".$_POST["Location"]."'";

mysql_query($edit);
header("Location:redirectpage.php");
}`redirection`

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID='".$_REQUEST['ID']."' ");  `//use WHERE`

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>`//end`